# Jasper iReport, subreport en header no se repite

Tags: ireport, jasper

Tengo un texto estático y un subreporte en mi page header, el texto estático se repite en todas las páginas como se supone que debe suceder, pero el subreporte únicamente se pinta en la primera página, **¿Cómo repetir el subreporte del header en todas las paginas?**

> *Configuración del reporte con el subreporte en el encabezado*

[image: Configuración del reporte con el subreporte en el encabezado]

> *Resultado del reporte en la primera página*

[image: Resultado del reporte en la primera página]

> *Resultado del reporte en la segunda página*

[image: Resultado del reporte en la segunda página]

Lo que deseo es obtener el mismo resultado de la primera página en las demas páginas generadas

Comment: Nuevamente te sugerimos revises el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento del sitio y revises [ask] para realizar preguntas y estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, saludos.

Comment: Se editó la pregunta, mas detalles no puedo poner

Comment: ¿que versión de JasperReports estas usando?

Comment: Estoy usando la versión 4.7.1